# Date conversion issue in swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on the iOS application where I have to get some data from the service and show it to users using UITableView. In that data there is a Date string that I need to show to user.

Everything is working as expected but I am unable to parse the date format. for example I have following date string

```
let dateString = "2018-02-27T09:45:12.887"
```

and the function that I am using is something like this

```
func getDateFromString(_ DateStr: String, _ format : String ) throws -> Date
{

    var date = Date()

    var dateString = DateStr


    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat =  format
    dateFormatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.ISO8601)! as Calendar
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") as Locale
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0) as TimeZone

    if let dateFromString = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {

    date = dateFromString

    }

    return date
}
```

**and I am calling this function as**

```
let date = getDateFromString("2018-02-27T09:45:12.887","yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFF")
```

And I am not getting the desired converted date. I do not know what is wrong here. Everything looks fine but the out put that I am getting is the converted date of current date. (That was expected as in case of no converted date I am returning current date)

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here and why it is not working??

Answer (score 2):

your date format is wrong use `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS"` instead, and replace T with whitespace. Here is an example

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let dateStr = "2018-02-27T09:45:12.887"
    let date = getDateFromString(dateStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "T", with: " "), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    print(date)
}

func getDateFromString(_ dateString: String, _ format: String ) -> Date {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
    return dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) ?? Date()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the format i think. I just changed the format and it started working like a charm .....

> here is the format I am using now **yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.F** previously I was using **yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.F**

Hope it will help someone in future.

Comment: `F` (which is for "Date of Week in Month") should be `SSS` ("Fractional Second" (three digits in your case)) instead

Answer (score 1):

DateFormatter just formats the string for your requirement. The date remains unaffected. If you wish to convert the acquired date into a suitable format for showing it to an end user, you need to retrieve the string after you change the format using dateformatter. Not the date, but the string from the date.